# PostGIS: Identifying the matching polygon in a query that involves a MultiPolygon

Tags: postgis, geojson

Suppose a table has a geo column `myGeoColumn` that contains a `MultiPolygon` as follows:

```
MULTIPOLYGON( ((-99 56,-52 18,-88 -27,-99 56))),((-77 56, 90 30, 92 36, -77 56)) )')
```

If I issue a query like this:

```
SELECT * from myTable where ST_Intersection(myGeoColumn, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-77 56)') is not null
```

then the query succeeds and I get back the row -- but I get back the entire `MultiPolygon` too.  I cannot determine which polygon was matched.

How can I enhance the query to only return the actual matching polygon inside the `MultiPolygon` (in the example above, polygon #2)?   I believe the same question applies if the column contains a `GeometryCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to break up the multipolygon before executing the st_intersection.

```
with polygon 
   as(select (st_dump(geom)).geom geom from mytable
      )    
select ST_Intersection(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-77 56)') from polygon
```

you are also intersecting a point and polygon...so you shouldn't ever get back an entire multipolygon like the query you provided. is that your entire query?

**updated with what I think you are after**

```
with polygon 
   as(select (st_dump(geom)).geom geom from mytable
      )    
select geom from polygon where st_intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-77 56)')
```

**Update 2**

Based on your comment this may be another way to do it

```
with 
  polygon_inter as(select (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom 
                     from mytable 
                     where ST_Intersects(geom,ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-77 56)')
  )
select geom from polygon_inter 
 where ST_Intersects(geom,ST_GeomFromText('POINT (-77 56)')
```

the 1st CTE will only select and break up the multipolygon that intersect the point (this alleviates the optimization fear of breaking up ALL the multipolygons) then the select after the cte will only select the INDIVIDUAL polygons that intersect the point

Comment: Yes, I crippled the example in editing it.   My bad.   Will PostGIS perform any query optimization with that CTE so that I don't dump an entire table of MultiPolygons that might not have any intersections?

Comment: Fixed the query to reflect @ziggy observation/correction

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by `Will PostGIS perform any query optimization with that CTE so that I don't dump an entire table of MultiPolygons that might not have any intersections?`

Comment: you do not want to use st_intersection in the where clause -- that is cutting the geometry. st_intersects is a spatial boolean t/f that you should use in the where clause